# Ruby Fun with Loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects like so: (I know it's ugly)

```
[
  { :application_type =>
       #<OrgSpecific::ApplicationType _id: 4cd2c13f8ed7df3230000002,
         org_parameters: { "CENTER_LOCATION" => [["Not Applicable"]],
                           "LEVELX" => [["Graduate"]],
                           "LOCATION" => [["Online"], ["University Campus"]]
                           },
         comment: "MSW",
         hide_deadline: false,
         payable_on_submission: true,
         name: "Graduate">,
    :requirement=>"available"
  },
  # (imagine more of these)
]
```

I want to create a method that loops through this array and returns an object with the application type Ids as properties and the value in the :requirement property as the value like so:

```
{"4cd2c13f8ed7df3230000002" => "available", "4cd2c13f8ed7df3230000003" => "available"}
```

but I'm so inexperienced with maps, lambdas, procs.  What's the easy way to do this?  I know with ruby I can probably do it with only a few lines.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your going to ask your question in the form of code, it will be easier to answer if the code is executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution but, simple.

```
your_array = [{:application_type =>"type", :requirement=>"available"}]

result_hash = {}
your_array.each{|x| res[x[:application_type]] = x[:requirement]}


puts result_hash #=> {"type"=>"available"}
```

Of course in your example you will need something like `x[:application_type].id`

**EDIT**: 
If you are looking for a one liner you could also do the following:

1. Use inject to keep track of the result hash for you.

   `your_array.inject({}){|i, x| i[x[:application_type]] = x[:requirement]; i}`
2. Use collect to return a set of [key, value] pairs, and then convert to a hash

   `Hash[your_array.collect{|x| [x[:application_type], x[:requirement]]}]`

Option [2] may be the most readable.

Comment: Well that's what I ended up with.  It's not pretty but thank you!

Comment: See my edit. I think both options are superior, the second option makes the intent of the code a little more obvious. (Turn the array of hashes into a single hash)